# enforcing at least one child in a foreign key constraint (or 1:1..n relationship)

Tags: postgresql, database-design

While trying to implement multi-language strings in a postgres DB, I came across ["Data Modeling for Multiple Languages (on Vertabelo)"](http://www.vertabelo.com/blog/technical-articles/data-modeling-for-multiple-languages-how-to-design-a-localization-ready-system). Especially "Approach #4", splitting non-translatable properties from translatable strings seems favorable to me:

- there is no need to differentiate between a "favored child" (transation) and other children
- no third table per object required
  (which really feels clunky and not (performance) efficient - read below)
- *please refer to the article for all pros & cons*

In order to enforce at least one translation (string) per object I tried to implement a 1:1..n relationship by adding a FK on the object table back to the object_string table, what leads to a circular reference of course.

*Have a look at the*

### Model

(using only a single property and string per object. Representative purpose only, actual DB is more complex)
[image: graphical model]

or use the psql dump:

```
CREATE TABLE language (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    rfc3066 character varying(10) NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE object (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    unit_string_id integer NOT NULL,
    property real NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE object_string (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    object_id integer NOT NULL,
    language_id integer NOT NULL,
    string varchar(100) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE ONLY object_string
    ADD CONSTRAINT unit_string_language_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (language_id) REFERENCES language(id) MATCH FULL ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE ONLY object_string
    ADD CONSTRAINT unit_string_unit_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (object_id) REFERENCES object(id) MATCH FULL ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE ONLY object
    ADD CONSTRAINT unit_unist_string_fkey FOREIGN KEY (unit_string_id) REFERENCES object_string(id) MATCH FULL;

 -- this constraint is not related to the question. just ensure only one translation per string --
ALTER TABLE ONLY object_string
    ADD CONSTRAINT unit_id_language_id_unique UNIQUE (object_id, language_id);
```

## Question

1. Keep in mind, that I'm going to implement as much as possible on the server side. Is this bad preference?
   (==> I plan to use views, i.e. with custom `ON INSERT DO INSTEAD`
   rules, to free the frontend from ideally any checking&logic requirements)
2. Is this circular reference still *that* disgusting / problematic **these days**?
   AND if it is, what is more preferable:

   - create all string columns in the object table and store the default language string there
   - implement the relationship using a third (cross-reference) table ?
     (I intended to avoid this, as it feels redundant, given the targeted approach is able to work elegantly. Btw: How much of a performance penalty could this be?)
3. Ignoring whether this approach is bad practice or not - out of curiosity:
   Is it possible to deal with that at all (without alleviating `NOT NULL` constraints)
4. Is it possible to deal with that even elegantly (using rules, triggers, whatever...)

Any experience or comments welcome!

Comment: I think [`DEFERRABLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-createtable.html) foreign keys could help you here.

Comment: @dezso Ive never had a violated FK constraint when trying to solve this with a view and a rule using a CTE query. The `NOT NULL` got me everytime though

Comment: A quick note: your FK definition allows an object A to reference an object_string that references a **different** object B. The FK should be corrected to `FOREIGN KEY (unit_string_id, id) REFERENCES object_string(id, object_id)` (and an appropriate UNIQUE constraint adedd on `object_string`.)

Comment: @ypercube: very good point. Going to update when I'm at home